# Wrap text of one col to another col with an image in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one row and two col in bootstrap, one with a text block and another with an image, but i want that the text wrap around the image, but i can't, it shows like 2 col divided. reduced to the basic, this is the html:

```
<div class="row ">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

<p class="fecha-noticia"><img src="images/calendar-orange.png"  class="img-responsive calendar-orange" alt="Responsive image 10" />28 Octubre 2014</p>
<p class="sumario">Gran representación de Aje Extremadura en la 56 jornada corresponsables.</p>
            <p>
Durante la inauguración, María Ángeles Muñoz, consejera de Empleo, Mujer y Política Social del Gobierno de Extremadura, ha asegurado que “el Gobierno de Extremadura ha trabajado muy duro para que la RSE sea una realidad en la región, no sólo siendo la primera Comunidad Autónoma que hemos desarrollado una Ley de RSE (2010), sino trabajando para su implantación en el tejido empresarial, que está conformado por pymes”.
            </p>
            <p>
 Muñoz resaltó diferentes iniciativas como la publicación desde hace tres años de la memoria de RSE, la aprobación del Gobierno hace unos meses de una moción para incorporar las clausulas sociales y medioambientales  en la contratación pública o el curso de homologación de auditores para verificar información no financiera en la aplicación ORSE. La consejera de Empleo, Mujer y Política Social avanzó que en breve “el Gobierno de Extremadura apoyará la contratación de personas para la integración de las RSE en la empresa y que en el primer trimestre de 2015 el Consejo Autonómico de RSE aprobará la primera estrategia de RSE de Extremadura”.
            </p>
            <p>
 El alcalde de Badajoz, Francisco Javier Fragoso, indicó que “la propia actividad de la Administración Pública es RSE y por eso su gestión tiene que ser responsable”. Fragoso consideró que “la RSE en el caso de Extremadura ayuda a mejorar el territorio porque las empresas, sobre todo pymes, se implican con su desarrollo”. Además dijo que “es necesario trabajar la responsabilidad individual para que la RSE siga creciendo”.  

            </p>

<P class="lastp-single">El director de Fundecyt, Antonio Verde, aseguró que “promovemos la RSE convencidos de que es un valor añadido para la empresa y la sociedad” y que “queremos ser un referente en Extremadura en materia de emprendimiento, innovación y RSE”. Puso como ejemplo el proyecto europeo DESUR en el que Fundecyt participó.</P>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">  
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/representacion.jpg" alt="vision" />

                   <img  src="images/compartir.png"  class="img-responsive compartir" alt="Responsive image 10" /></div>


    </div>

    </div>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/k40on7ww/

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you use columns if you didn't want columns?

Comment: Also, when using `col-sm-6`, for example, `col-md-6` and `col-lg-6` are redundant.

Comment: Because i need to use with bootstrap.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Because the img need to be divided with 50% percent and get responsive when it resizing, and the col does this very well.

Comment: Remove the columns separting the image from the text, and then apply a specific style to the img tag to float it to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the columns, then do this:

```
.vision.pull-right {
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/k40on7ww/3)**